# How to define port range in nftables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nftables

I want to open a range of TCP ports in `nftables` on my servers.

Normally, in netfilter/iptables I can write the rule like this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp 1000:2000 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried to write in the same way in `/etc/nftables.conf`

```
tcp dport {1000:2000} accept
```

but `nft` reports

```
/etc/nftables.conf:24:15-24: Error: mapping outside of map context
     tcp dport {1000:2000} accept
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 10):

A simple dash without braces should do the trick:

`tcp dport 1000-2000 accept`

More examples of ranges and sets can be found in the official wiki [wiki.nftables.org Intervals](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Intervals)